# Clojure - Adding pairs of numbers in a vector

Tags: clojure

I have a vector `[1 2 3 4]`. Is there a way of adding each pair to get `[(+ 1 2) (+ 2 3) (+ 3 4)]`

I tried

```
(loop [x 0] 
  (when (< x (count y)) 
    (+ (nth y x) (nth y (+ 1 x))) 
    (recur (+ x 1))))
```

But I get an out of bounds error `IndexOutOfBoundsException   clojure.lang.PersistentVector.arrayFor (PersistentVector.java:158)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way:

```
(->> [1 2 3 4]
     (partition 2 1)
     (mapv (partial reduce +)))
;;=> [3 5 7]
```

The main problem I see with the approach you were taking is that there is no accumulator in the `loop` `recur` form. Another problem is that you are using `when` rather than `if`.

Answer (score 5):

```
(fn [xs]
  (map + xs (rest xs)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a destructuring example:

```
(->> [1 2 3 4]
     (partition 2 1)
     (mapv (fn [[f s]] (+ f s))))
```